# How to fetch all the paths from root to leaf (DFS way) in Neo4j and return the result containing nodes and relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph where I used following cypher to display all the paths in the Graph . This returns all the nodes .
CQL : MATCH p=(root {id: 'start'})-[*]->(leaf) RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | x.name) AS result;

I want to return nodes and edges so that layman can understand what all paths exists from root to leaf in the graph .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of all available paths could be obtained as follows.

```
MATCH p=(root {id: 'start'})-[*]->(leaf)  
// limit the match to the ones that end at a leaf
WHERE NOT (leaf)-->()


RETURN DISTINCT REDUCE (s='', r in RELATIONSHIPS(p) | 
               s+
               CASE WHEN s='' THEN '('+startNode(r).name + ')-[:'+ type(r)+']->('+ endNode(r).name+')'
                    ELSE '-[:'+ type(r)+']->('+ endNode(r).name+')'
               END
       ) AS path
```

Comment: Thanks , This worked well . One additional question is if in the RETURN statement I want to add certain properties of nodes which are present in few nodes only then how to do that . e.g if certain nodes has property 'expression'  then how to insert that.

Comment: @priya  You could insert    +COALESCE(startNode(r).expression,'')    so that if there is not such a property, an empty string is added